# Pull Latest Forum Posts within WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Hopefully this is the easiest question ever asked. I have a WordPress site with BBP installed. I want to be able to pull the latest BBP posts in a php query I can use throughout the site. What is easiest way of doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try wp-o-matic? did it do what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [wp-o-matic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-o-matic/) plugin that watches an RSS feed and uses cron to pull RSS entries. It also has nice features to decide which data you want to pull, and how you want to format it.